# Apply webpack config to electron main process

Tags: webpack, electron, babeljs

Given an application built using [chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate), I'd like to apply the webpack config to the main process (`app/main.js` file too).

Indeed, as-is, webpack loaders are only taken into account into the renderer process (which correspond to all files except `app/main.js` and `app/menu.js`).
This makes code reusability difficult, especially if one want to use redux in the main process (useful for example in the menu or to handle multiple windows).

For example, TypeScript loader is not called, so the `main` cannot be a TypeScript file and cannot import ts files as well, and it leads to other similar issue with imports.

Note that babel can be used however, so basic ES6 is ok even in the main process.

So, it's all in the title: how could I set up the app so that the `app/main.js` somehow take the webpack config into account, or is built before app launch ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm trying to get typescript working on the main process of an electron app, although not using the same boilerplate as you were (I'm on [basic-electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate) instead).

Comment: Hi @Jules I posted an answer, tell me if it helped. I simply added a specific config for the main process based on existing one and added a build step.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this I added a specific script and config for the main process:

```
"build-main-development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.electron.development.js --progress",

"build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.electron.js --progress --profile --colors"
```

Here is the config. You'll need to set `electron-main` as the target.

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/main.development'],
  output: {
    filename: './main.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new BabiliPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ],

  /**
   * https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer#how-this-module-works
   */
  target: 'electron-main',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks more likely to work than what I tried, which was trying to set up webpack to do both targets in the same configuration -- it worked, except that launching the main process was sometimes happening before the renderer process code was ready.